# Div is not inline when in mobile display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code I placed every label and span in a `class=col-sm-6`

echo '
        
        
        Contact Information

```
    <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">Full Name : </label>
    <span class="head9 halfR">'.$fullname1.'</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">Birthdate : </label>
    <span class="head9 halfR">'.$bday.'</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">Email : </label>
    <span class="head9 halfR">'.$email.'</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">Address : </label>
    <div class="halfR">
    <span class="head9">'.$address.'</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">City : </label>
    <div class="halfR">
    <span class="head9">'.$city.'</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">State : </label>
    <span class="head9 halfR">'.$state.'</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">Zip Code : </label>
    <span class="head9 halfR">'.$zip.'</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">Phone Number : </label>
    <span class="head9 halfR">'.$phone.'</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">Fax : </label>
    <span class="head9 halfR">'.$fax.'</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="head6">Company Position : </label>
    <span class="head9 halfR">'.$position.'</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div> 


    ';
```

and it looks like this (desktop view)[image]
but in mobile view, it looks like this. the label and span are not align.

[image] 
how can i make it align?

btw,class halfR contains this..

```
.halfR{
  width:60%;
  float:right;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: can you share jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

It's not inline because your labels are too long that the 60% width of the .halfR has to overflow to the next line.

Try adding a max-width to the labels using media queries for mobile view (or preferably adding a max-width and then removing it using media queries for a mobile first approach)

```
.col-sm-6 label{
    max-width: 35%;
}
```

As Arun states in his answer, you should also wrap each group in a div with the class row. This won't stop the inline issue, but will make sure that your rows stay together.

Answer (score 0):

use class `row` as shown below

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```